# wrong encoding with JSF input

Tags: jsf, character-encoding, jboss

I use java 6 jsf1.2 and rich faces 3.3.3 on jboss 7 linux.

Everything worked fine on windows + tomcat but when I moved to linux + jboss I got a problem where  h:inputText  in hebrew would get to the server side as jibrish( @#@!# ) instead of the hebrew letters. all of the files are utf-8.

How do I fix this encoding problem?

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be configured in `/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`. Add the following piece right *after* the `</extensions>`:

```xml
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
</system-properties>
```